# phone bluetooth on still asking turn on bluetooth in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hi in the below code already phone bluetooth on still it is asking me to turn on the pop-up in the below code.

Can any one help me where I did the wrong.

```
public void checkPermissionOffline(Activity activity, String value) {
        Log.d("value jyothi", value);
        if (bleAdapter == null) {
            final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            bleAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        }
        if (value != null && value.equals(String.valueOf(Constant.BLE_DISABLED))) {
            requestBluetoothEnable(activity);
        } else {
            if (!bleAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                bluetoothPermissionResult(Constant.BLE_ENABLED);
                Toast.makeText(activity,"ble enabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                bluetoothPermissionResult(Constant.BLE_DISABLED);
                Toast.makeText(activity,"ble disabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (bleAdapter != null && bleAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    if (!hasLocationPermissions(activity)) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Enphase app requesting location permission");
                        Timber.tag("PES").i("Enphase app requesting location permission");
                        requestLocationPermission(activity);
                    } else {

                        Log.e(TAG, "Enphase app requesting DeviceLocation permission");
                        Timber.tag("PES").i("Enphase app requesting DeviceLocation permission");
                       requestDeviceLocationSettings(activity);
                    }
                } else {
                    requestBluetoothEnableTesting(activity);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

permission no need to ask already bluetooth is on

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Line 10 of your source code contains an error.